# Unable to get response from fetch request using 127.0.0.1 in React-native

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, react-native

I am using rest services to get the response for my react-native android app. Whenever I am using the localhost(i tried with 127.0.0.1) with port 8080 but fetch is giving me [TypeError: Network request failed]. Fetch request is working fine without localhost. Rest service is working fine when used with Postman.

I am running my code using expo.
And for backend dependency using Maven.

I tried with both physical device and emulator both failed, checked with port 9090.
I tried to change the server address in the application.properties file after which spring-boot backend stopped which is due to server address configuration problem.
(Error:
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 9090 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 9090, or configure this application to listen on another port.)

insertPost() {

```
return fetch('http://127.0.0.1:9090/getPost/PO397ba3306cc211e98f8249277cd661ec')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json)
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

console.log(json) should print the object returned from fetch.

Comment: Has your spring-boot application started to run? As in can you hit your controller via an API call itself? If you have a service running on that port, why not change your spring boot config to deploy on a different port in your application.properties file. `server.port=some other port`

Answer (score 4):

You should use the 'IP address' of your system

```
http://YourIpAddress:9090/getPost/PO397ba3306cc211e98f8249277cd661ec
```

Please check your connected device and system in the same network. Please refer below documentation:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device

Comment: and if you want to use the specefic port you need to reverse it. for example `adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't `return` the fetch function. Try to remove the `return` word to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this,

http://10.0.2.2:portnumber/

> **10.0.2.2** - Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

Comment: how to set this alias

Comment: Try using redir add tcp:oldportnumber:newportnumber
Refer https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html

Comment: The following command sets up a redirection that handles all incoming TCP connections to your host (development) machine on 127.0.0.1:5000 and will pass them through to the emulated system on 10.0.2.2:6000
      "redir add tcp:5000:6000"

Comment: have you tried this before as i tried but still getting errors via this method as it is giving error(console.error: "Getting Error for fetch function", {"line"........."sourceURL":"http://192.168.43.252:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify.......) 

btw problem already get solved by using the solution provided by Subhash Patel.